# how to get response from php file?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently trying to connect my phpmyadmin server with android studio.
I'm using the emulator if it matters.
I made some php files to receive data and change data in my database.

checkuserexist.php

```
<?php
require('con1.php');

if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_GET['username']);
    if (!empty($username)) {
            $username_query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'");
            $username_result = mysqli_num_rows($username_query);
            if($username_result == 0)
                print $existornot = "NotExist";
            else print $existornot = "Exist";
    }
}
?>
```

And in my Android Studio program:

```
  URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/fives/checkuserexist.php?username=yariv");
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
  InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(stream );

//put output stream into a string
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isReader );
  String result = "";
  String line;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
  result += line;
  }
  br.close();
```

InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream(); 
return an exeption:
 failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
How to solve this exeption?

Comment: This is more of a Java question that a PHP question.  Check out this post, the TLDR of it all is you need to use a BufferedReader on the `conn.getInputStream()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805107/httpurlconnection-how-to-get-the-xml-response-into-a-string

Comment: try to use local ip instead localhost
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378501/how-to-browse-localhost-on-android-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could echo out some JSON in the PHP file and use the JSONObject/JSONArray classes in android

Comment: What kind of exception?

Comment: failed to connect to /192.168.1.20 (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Comment: Are you sure your server is running on port 8080?

Answer (score 0):

should check the emulator network setting to see what is your main machine IP address.

second way :
open `run` menu, type `cmd` and again type `ipconfig`.
you can also try other IP v4 addresses found in the here:

Comment: my IP v4 is 192.168.1.20
So i tried:
url = new URL("http://192.168.1.20:8080/fives/checkuserexist.php");
and the exeption is : 
failed to connect to /192.168.1.20 (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Comment: I think you should have other IP addresses too. check emulator network settings.

Comment: And another thing you should do is to encode every url param in android